# drupal 8 view filtering criteria works on preview but not on block

Tags: view, drupal

Im creating a view in drupal 8 to show the most commented articles. Im using as filtering criteria: "published = yes", "Content type = article", "comment amount > 0".

I was hoping to get published articles that got at least 1 comment; all this showing inside a block in the right sidebar.

In the view preview everything works fine, showing the articles that got at least 1 comment and ignoring articles with 0 comments (when the view is created and later on).

The problem arises in the block because it only shows articles that got at least 1 comment at the time the view is created, after that it freezes and do not update the articles when new comments are added, even when the view's preview works just fine.

I've eliminated the "comment amount > 0" filtering criteria and the block updates the articles when new comments are added. But once a put it back the block freezes again.

Honestly I have no idea why, much more when the preview works perfectly fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could be that block content is cached. If you clear the cache is the block updated? Check also when editing block display under Advanced -> Other - Caching what kind of caching is selected. Try with "none".

Comment: Gee thanks man. You're a life saver. That was precisely the problem.